# Destination goals tracking "Unique Pageviews" or "Visits"?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

In Google analytics, what's being tracked in destination goals? Is it visits to a page or unique page views? Is there anyway to change what the goal can track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Destination goals work is they get logged when ever anyone hits the URL.  So if the person has been there before it will be logged a second time.

To answer your question its not unique and i don't think you can change that.  Only way i can think of to maybe get around that would be to set a cookie on there browser and use that to change the URL adding something like ?hasbeenhere=1 and then set up a dynamic URL that would ignore it in the Goal.  But i haven't tried that it was just an idea.

[Dynamically generated or variable URLs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#dynamic)

I hope this helps.

Comment: For a group of pages, this is the information I currently get:               Behavior>Site Content>All Pages: 70 Pageviews, 41 Unique Pageviews, 9 Entrances                                                                       Conversions>Goals>Goal Flow: 40 Visits.                                           There's a not a huge difference in goal flow reporting and Unique Pageviews as of now. But it might increase. This is for a specific segment of users and I haven't set up the goals only a week ago. So I cant look at conversion rates yet. So it cannot be pageviews, what do you think?

Comment: Another example of this case:- Segment: Returning Visitors; ....Behavior>Site Content>Content DrillDown> Unique Pageviews: 150, Pageviews: 223; Entrances: 12; .....Conversions>Goals>Goal Flow> Visits: 71?! Why this discrepancy?